# python regex - select words after pattern

Tags: python, regex

text:

3. MANAGEMENT, FOOD EMPLOYEE AND CONDITIONAL EMPLOYEE; KNOWLEDGE, RESPONSIBILITIES AND REPORTING - Comments: NO WRITTEN EMPLOYEE HEALTH POLICY ON SITE. MUST PROVIDE FOR ALL EMPLOYEES. PRIORITY FOUNDATION VIOLATION 7-38-010 CITATION ISSUED. | 5. PROCEDURES FOR RESPONDING TO VOMITING AND DIARRHEAL EVENTS - Comments: NO WRITTEN CLEANING PROCEDURE OR REQUIRED EQUIPMENT FOR A VOMITING/DIARRHEA EVENT. MUST PROVIDE. PRIORITY FOUNDATION VIOLATION 7-38-005 CITATION ISSUED. | 25. CONSUMER ADVISORY PROVIDED FOR RAW/UNDERCOOKED FOOD - Comments: MENU DOES NOT DISCLOSE AND INFORM CONSUMERS THE SPECIFIC MENU ITEMS THAT ARE RAW OR UNDER COOKED AND A POTENTIAL HAZARD OF CONSUMING SUCH FOOD. MUST PROVIDE A CONSUMER ADVISORY THAT DISCLOSES AND REMINDS CUSTOMERS OF SUCH ITEMS. PRIORITY FOUNDATION VIOLATION. NO CITATION ISSUED.  | 38.

Question:

The sections of the text include sections 3, 5, 25, and 38 (followed by starting index). I want to extract all texts from one section after '- Comments:' and before the starting index of the next section.

```
def comments(x):
    result = []
    for elem in df['Violations']:
        matches = re.findall(r'\d+\. (.*?)(?: - |\r?\n|$)', elem)
        result.extend(matches)
    print(result)
```

The attached code is doing the totally opposite extraction which only extracts the words before '- Comments:', how can I change it?

Many thanks

Comment: if you want after `Comments` then use `Comments`  in regex. Maybe `"Comments: (.+) \|` or `'Comments: ([^\|]*) \|'`

Comment: sorry, I am very new to regex. Could you write the full code in re.findall( )? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want text between `Comments:` and `|` then use these values in regex.

```
'Comments: ([^\|]*) \|'
```

It uses `()` to catch only chars between `Comments:` and `|` but   different then `|`  (see `[^\|]`).

Because `|` has special meaning in regex so I use `\|` to use it as normal char in text.

---

Or

```
'Comments: (.*?) \|'
```

which uses `?` to get chars different then `|`

---

```
import re

elem = '''MANAGEMENT, FOOD EMPLOYEE AND CONDITIONAL EMPLOYEE; KNOWLEDGE, RESPONSIBILITIES AND REPORTING - Comments: NO WRITTEN EMPLOYEE HEALTH POLICY ON SITE. MUST PROVIDE FOR ALL EMPLOYEES. PRIORITY FOUNDATION VIOLATION 7-38-010 CITATION ISSUED. | 5. PROCEDURES FOR RESPONDING TO VOMITING AND DIARRHEAL EVENTS - Comments: NO WRITTEN CLEANING PROCEDURE OR REQUIRED EQUIPMENT FOR A VOMITING/DIARRHEA EVENT. MUST PROVIDE. PRIORITY FOUNDATION VIOLATION 7-38-005 CITATION ISSUED. | 25. CONSUMER ADVISORY PROVIDED FOR RAW/UNDERCOOKED FOOD - Comments: MENU DOES NOT DISCLOSE AND INFORM CONSUMERS THE SPECIFIC MENU ITEMS THAT ARE RAW OR UNDER COOKED AND A POTENTIAL HAZARD OF CONSUMING SUCH FOOD. MUST PROVIDE A CONSUMER ADVISORY THAT DISCLOSES AND REMINDS CUSTOMERS OF SUCH ITEMS. PRIORITY FOUNDATION VIOLATION. NO CITATION ISSUED. | 38.'''

#matches = re.findall('Comments: ([^\|]*) \|', elem)
matches = re.findall('Comments: (.*?) \|', elem)

#print(matches)

for item in matches:
    print(item)
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
NO WRITTEN EMPLOYEE HEALTH POLICY ON SITE. MUST PROVIDE FOR ALL EMPLOYEES. PRIORITY FOUNDATION VIOLATION 7-38-010 CITATION ISSUED.
---
NO WRITTEN CLEANING PROCEDURE OR REQUIRED EQUIPMENT FOR A VOMITING/DIARRHEA EVENT. MUST PROVIDE. PRIORITY FOUNDATION VIOLATION 7-38-005 CITATION ISSUED.
---
MENU DOES NOT DISCLOSE AND INFORM CONSUMERS THE SPECIFIC MENU ITEMS THAT ARE RAW OR UNDER COOKED AND A POTENTIAL HAZARD OF CONSUMING SUCH FOOD. MUST PROVIDE A CONSUMER ADVISORY THAT DISCLOSES AND REMINDS CUSTOMERS OF SUCH ITEMS. PRIORITY FOUNDATION VIOLATION. NO CITATION ISSUED.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern captures as least as possible text in a group before either  `-` , a newline or end of string and does not match any part with `Comments:`

You could change it by matching comments, and add a capture group for the text after it

```
\d+\. .*?(?: - Comments:\s*)(.*?)(?: \||$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ms1kcX/1)

A bit more precise match could be matching the start of each text, which is digits, a dot and a space, and then match until the first occurrence of -Comments: without crossing the start of another text.

That after Comments, you can use a capture group to capture until the next occurrence of a text, or assert the end of the string if it is the last one.

Using re.findall will return the value of capture group 1.

```
\b\d+\. (?:(?!\d+\. |- Comments:).)*- Comments:\s*(.*?)(?: \||$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `\d+\.`  Match 1+ digits, a dot and space
- `(?:(?!\d+\. |- Comments:).)*` Match any char if directly to the right there is not pattern `\d+\.`  or `- Comments`
- `- Comments:\s*` Match `- Comments:` followed by optional whitespace chars
- `(.*?)` Capture group 1, match any char as least as possible
- `(?: \||$)` Match either

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/26teDh/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/OqJ8pl)

Example

```
import re

regex = r"\b\d+\. (?:(?!\d+\. |- Comments:).)*- Comments:\s*(.*?)(?: \||$)"

s = "3. MANAGEMENT, FOOD EMPLOYEE AND CONDITIONAL EMPLOYEE; KNOWLEDGE, RESPONSIBILITIES AND REPORTING - Comments: NO WRITTEN EMPLOYEE HEALTH POLICY ON SITE. MUST PROVIDE FOR ALL EMPLOYEES. PRIORITY FOUNDATION VIOLATION 7-38-010 CITATION ISSUED. | 5. PROCEDURES FOR RESPONDING TO VOMITING AND DIARRHEAL EVENTS - Comments: NO WRITTEN CLEANING PROCEDURE OR REQUIRED EQUIPMENT FOR A VOMITING/DIARRHEA EVENT. MUST PROVIDE. PRIORITY FOUNDATION VIOLATION 7-38-005 CITATION ISSUED. | 25. CONSUMER ADVISORY PROVIDED FOR RAW/UNDERCOOKED FOOD - Comments: MENU DOES NOT DISCLOSE AND INFORM CONSUMERS THE SPECIFIC MENU ITEMS THAT ARE RAW OR UNDER COOKED AND A POTENTIAL HAZARD OF CONSUMING SUCH FOOD. MUST PROVIDE A CONSUMER ADVISORY THAT DISCLOSES AND REMINDS CUSTOMERS OF SUCH ITEMS. PRIORITY FOUNDATION VIOLATION. NO CITATION ISSUED.  | 38. "

print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Output

```
[
'NO WRITTEN EMPLOYEE HEALTH POLICY ON SITE. MUST PROVIDE FOR ALL EMPLOYEES. PRIORITY FOUNDATION VIOLATION 7-38-010 CITATION ISSUED.', 
'NO WRITTEN CLEANING PROCEDURE OR REQUIRED EQUIPMENT FOR A VOMITING/DIARRHEA EVENT. MUST PROVIDE. PRIORITY FOUNDATION VIOLATION 7-38-005 CITATION ISSUED.', 
'MENU DOES NOT DISCLOSE AND INFORM CONSUMERS THE SPECIFIC MENU ITEMS THAT ARE RAW OR UNDER COOKED AND A POTENTIAL HAZARD OF CONSUMING SUCH FOOD. MUST PROVIDE A CONSUMER ADVISORY THAT DISCLOSES AND REMINDS CUSTOMERS OF SUCH ITEMS. PRIORITY FOUNDATION VIOLATION. NO CITATION ISSUED. '
]
```